# Output form values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

New to JavaScript here. How do I have an output in JS that changes (when a button is pressed) based on the value of an HTML form? Here's what I have so far:

```
<form> Number: <input name="num" type="number" value="20" /></form>

<button onclick = ?????output num?????> Click Me </button>
```

What goes where the `?????output num?????` is? I *think* that I should be using the `document.getElementById(id)` syntax, but I'm not sure how to get that to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just listen for value change events from the input field and grab the value each time.

I'm not sure I quite understand what you're asking here or what you're trying to do in reference to the `?????output num?????`, so I just had it log the number that's put in:

```
document.getElementsByName("num")[0].addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = "console.log(" + this.value + ")"; // This assumes that it's the only button the page; I'd give it an ID
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" id="num" name="number" value="20"/>    
<button onclick="alertNum()"></button>
<script>
function alertNum() {
   var num = document.getElementById('num').value;
   alert(num);
}
</script>
```

Ensure you define the id in your html node.